# Oracle And .Net SqlDataSource

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm using the Oracle.DataAccess.Client with an 11g database. I've setup a SQL datasource like so.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleRoadmap %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleRoadmap.ProviderName %>" 


    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM &quot;FILES&quot; WHERE (&quot;FILE_NAME&quot; LIKE '%' + ? + '%')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchValue" Name="FILE_NAME" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

ORA-00911: invalid character when I run this. However if I hard code the FILE_NAME then it works.

> "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE FILE_NAME LIKE '%.zip%'

I've tried the same thing but against SQL Server and had no issues with it.

Thanks

Comment: Change '&FILE_NAME` and See what happen?

Comment: I've changed the code slightly didn't realise that @parms were only relevant to SQL Server. I get a slightly different error now.

Comment: Concatenation in Oracle uses || - is that what's needed here instead of + ?

Comment: I did try that, but I think || is for concatenating a string not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer I was looking for but I have dynamically created the SelectCommand for the SQLDatasource in the page code behind and this works around the problem.

I suspect the issue was something to do with the statement and variable being passed to Oracle separately and the error was produced when the full statement is created in Oracle. Unfortunately I don't have access to the Oracle logs to see what is coming through.